# one month range date will work on past dates jquery ui

Tags: jquery

one month range date will work on past dates

for example

if i am selected (from date) 2016-september-07

future dates will disable in (#to_date)

https://jsfiddle.net/swaroop206/vpe54c29/4/

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$('#from_date').datepicker( {
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true, 
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
         maxDate: new Date(),

        onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
                var orginalDate = new Date(selectedDate);
                var monthsAddedDate = new Date(new Date(orginalDate).setMonth(orginalDate.getMonth() + 1));

                $("#to_date").datepicker("option", 'minDate', selectedDate);
                $("#to_date").datepicker("option", 'maxDate', monthsAddedDate);
            }
    }).click(function(){
        $('.ui-datepicker-calendar').show();
    });
    $('#to_date').datepicker( {
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true, 
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
         maxDate: new Date(),

        onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
                var orginalDate = new Date(selectedDate);
                var monthsAddedDate = new Date(new Date(orginalDate).setMonth(orginalDate.getMonth() - 1));

                $("#from_date").datepicker("option", 'minDate', monthsAddedDate);
                $("#from_date").datepicker("option", 'maxDate', selectedDate);
            }
    }).click(function(){
        $('.ui-datepicker-calendar').show();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: What output you want?

Comment: Means if you select 5th sept. then in todate 6th on-words dates to be disabled.

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: Did you see my answer?

Comment: yes https://jsfiddle.net/swaroop206/vpe54c29/4/ please check this demo

Comment: one month range date will work on past dates jquery ui

Comment: every thing working but iam selecting #from_date 7th on-words future dates are open in (#to_date)

Comment: you want to open todate automatically?

Comment: no, first step: you click on #from_date,2nd step:you selected date on 2016-september-07,3rd step:you selected on #to date future date are not disable

Comment: But you want it disable it after one month date right?

Comment: future dates will disable,but iam selecting 2016-sept-07 future dates will not disable in #to_date

Comment: you want like this: https://jsfiddle.net/atate143/vpe54c29/5/

Comment: today date(2016-sept-07) future dates will disable in #todate,you select this date(2016-june-05) in #from_date, #to_date will show one moth restriction(2016-july-05) remaing will disabe

Comment: for example yor are searching mail data,how search future dates.today is (2016-sept-07),how to search tomorrow mail,that why i want to disable future dates

Comment: sorry can't help.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are using `datetimepicker` for changing the option in runtime. You should use `datepicker` function instead.

Change This:

```
    $("#to_date").datetimepicker("option", 'minDate', selectedDate);
    $("#to_date").datetimepicker("option", 'maxDate', monthsAddedDate);
```

TO

```
    $("#to_date").datepicker("option", 'minDate', selectedDate);
    $("#to_date").datepicker("option", 'maxDate', monthsAddedDate);
```